# visual studio Display, how to access activity bar?

Tags: python, visual-studio-2019

I am in the Microsoft Visual Studio environment, most screenshots of this environment show an activity bar in the left sidebar. However, I cannot get this to appear in my display, I have sought to access this activity bar in view but cannot see any reasonable options.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps:

1. Open the Command Palette ( Ctrl + Shift + P ) and type Keyboard Shortcuts.
2. Click on Toggle Activity Bar Visibility, and choose your shortcut using the
   keyboard!
3. It's done!

Answer (score 0):

On Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 if you check on the "Debug" menu, you can find other windows that are helpful when the system is running.

I'm not sure which window you are looking for, but there's a "Diagnostic Tools" that could be the one.

Comment: Thank you, I have looked at this option. The diagnostics tool cannot be run until debugging occurs. I wonder if the could be a coding problem though? I don't think it could be, more of a settings issue I think.

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to see on this "activity bar". Visual Studio has a lot of different windows, that you can activate in different menu options. Although there are some features that only exist on the Enterprise version.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is from Visual Studio Code and not Visual Studio 2019 but I suspect they are most likely similar..

Press F1 and type "View: Toggle Activity Bar Visibility" and click on it when it shows up.  That should make your activity bar visible again.

Comment: Doesn't seem to occur, it actually send me to the microsoft online resource. thank you